# Is the inclusion map in the Sobolev embedding theorem a surjective map?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the Sobolev space of all real valued functions on 
$\mathbb{R}^n$ whose first $k$ weak derivatives are in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. 
Assume that 
$$ \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{p} - \frac{k-l}{n}$$
and $k >l$. 
The Sobolev embedding theorem states that the inclusion map 
$$ i : W^{k,p} \rightarrow W^{l,q} $$ 
is a bounded linear operator. My question is the following: 
is $i$ surjective? At the very least, is the image of $i$ closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not surjective and the image is not closed.

Example: Take $n = 2,  k = 1, p = 1$ and hence $q = 2$. Let $f$ be the indicator function of the unit square $[-1,1]^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. It is in $L^\infty$ and hence in $L^2$, but clearly its distributional derivative is not in $L^1$ (it's a signed measure and supported on the boundary of the square). Since $C^\infty_0$ functions are dense in $L^2$ and belong to $W^{1,1}$, the image of the embedding isn't closed either. It is, however, dense.

Comment: I see. Its clear from your example in general its not surjective (in fact not even closed). Is it ever surjective (or closed), i.e., surjective for some specific values of k, p, l and q? Or at least closed?

Comment: If $k > \ell$, the image is never closed.